# Finding average value of clusters in a 2D plot

Tags: c++, statistics

I'm trying to come up with a method in C++ to take the average value or median of each cluster shown in the scatter plot.

[image: Text]

What is the simplest method you can think of to do this?
K-means algorithms can quickly become complex. Is there an easier method given that all my datasets exhibit this same increasing step pattern?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the most naive and non-robust solution.  How about just having a maximum-difference threshold to separate clusters.  If two adjacent data points are within this tolerance level, then they are in the same cluster.  Such an approach is not good at handling outliers.  Anyway, with this data, it looks like you could choose a tolerance of about 25, being roughly half of the typical "step".

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I was thinking the same. That would be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easier method given that all my datasets exhibit this same increasing step pattern?

I have to assume some data types for you and also assuming you are comfortable with C++ algorithms and data structure library

```
using ClusterID = size_t;
using Point = std::pair<double, double>;

std::unordered_map<ClusterID, std::vector<Point>> clusterAverage;
```

Linearly scan the points, if they are *close enough* (choose a threshold for "closeness"), if they are out of threshold, assign the point to a new `ClusterID`.
Later, find an average/median of each group from `clusterAverage`

You could potentially find the average while putting into a clusterID, no need to add the entire vector of points. (`std::nth_element`).

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is an excellent method. I'll mark this correct if nobody chimes in with a bit more code on this implementation.